# Refresh DataGrid data on TreeViewItem selection change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I was able to implement Tree View using the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

Now I have attached the below Data Grid to it for displaying the city details like Area, Population, TimeZone etc.I was able to receive the event IsSelected upon selecting the City name from the treeview using example. But how do I bind the data of City model (Area, Population, TimeZone ) to a datagrid in the .xaml ? I tried using the CityViewModel directly but it never populates the data.CityViewModel has an observableCollection of "CityTown"( with props like Area, Population, TimeZone etc) property called "CityTowns" which I am populating when IsSelected is fired.My Tree View only has Region -> State -> City hierarchy. City towns should  be displayed in grid not in tree.

```
    //DemoWindow.xaml content:
    <TabControl>
          <TabItem Header="Load Towns">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <advanced: LoadOnDemandControl/>
             <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=local.CityViewModel.CityTowns}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"  
                 >
                   <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Popluation}" Header="Popluation"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Revenue}" Header="Revenue"/> 
                      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TimeZone}" Header="TimeZone"/>
                       <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Area}" Header="Area"/>
                  </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
          </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
 </TabControl>

 //LoadOnDemandCcontrol.xaml:
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Regions}">
          <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <!-- 
            This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a TreeViewItemViewModel. 
            -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
              <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
              <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
              <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
              <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
          </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

          <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
              DataType="{x:Type local:RegionViewModel}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
              >
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Region.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RegionName}" />
              </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
              DataType="{x:Type local:StateViewModel}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
              >
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\State.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StateName}" />
              </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CityViewModel}">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\City.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CityName}" />
              </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
          </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>

 //CityTown.cs content:
 public class CityTown
 {
    public int Area { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    public int Revenue { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
 }

 //CityViewModel.cs cocntent
public class CityViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel
{
    readonly City _city;

    public CityViewModel(City city, StateViewModel parentState)
        : base(parentState, false)
    {
        _city = city;
    }

    public string CityName
    {
        get { return _city.CityName; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<CityTown> _CityTowns;

    public ObservableCollection<CityTown>    CityTowns
    {
        get { return Database.GetTowns(CityName); }
        set { _CityTowns = value; }
    }

}

//LoadOnDemandDemoControl.xaml.cs content:
public partial class LoadOnDemandDemoControl : UserControl
  {
    public LoadOnDemandDemoControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Region[] regions = Database.GetRegions();
        CountryViewModel viewModel = new CountryViewModel(regions);
        base.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete XAML, including your `DataContext` declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by defining the `SelectedValuePath` property for `TreeView` xaml element class and used the same in `DataGrid` element -> `ItemsSoruce` property -> `Path` -> `SelectedItem.ViewModelDataCollection`.